# Matrices over a finite field: matrices for which some unipotent $U$ satisfies Trace$(ZU)=0$ for all $Z$ in the commutant

Tags: linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, matrices, finite-fields

Let $p$ be an odd prime number, let $A\in M_p(\mathbb{F}_p)$ be a $p$-by-$p$ matrix with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_p$, let $C(A)$ be the commutant of $A$, and let $N\in M_p(\mathbb{F}_p)$ be a nilpotent matrix. Suppose that
$$
\operatorname{Trace}\bigl(Z(I_p+N)\bigr)=0
\quad\text{for every $Z\in C(A)$.}
$$
Is it necessarily true that $A$ is cyclic (its minimal polynomial has degree $p$)?

Experiments with a computer prove that the result is true when $p=3$.

Comment: Is there any relationship between $A$ and $N$?

Comment: @LSpice Visibly no. Thinking of Trace(AB) as a pairing, it asks: if $C(A)$ is orthogonal to some unipotent matrix, is $A$ cyclic? An instance of $A$ with this property is $\mathrm{diag}(0,1,\dots,p-1)$, with $N$ the matrix with all $1$ entries — precisely $A$ is cyclic then.

Comment: @YCor, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463933/matrices-over-a-finite-field#comment1204638_463933), I am not sure what you mean.  Certainly it is visible that the question includes no relationship between $A$ and $N$; I was simply asking whether it meant to do so.  (Maybe it would have been clearer if I asked "Is there meant to be any relationship …?")  The only one who can answer that is @‍loupblanc, or, I guess, indirect evidence could be provided by proving the result true with no further assumption on $N$.

Comment: @LSpice my point is that after thinking about the question for a while, it sounds very likely that the question is correctly posed. Your request seems to arise from the assumption that the question is ill-posed.

Comment: @LSpice: $N$ is required to satisfy $\textrm{tr}(Z(1+N))=0$ for all $Z\in C(A)$, which is a condition that depends on $A$.

Comment: @LSpice $N$ is any nilpotent matrix; it doesn't depend on $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are counterexamples with $p=5$.

Let me restate the question. For a square matrix $A$ over any field, write $Y(A)=\{M:\forall Z\in C(A):\operatorname{Tr}(MZ)=0\}.$. Your question is whether $A$ non-cyclic implies that $Y(A)$ contains no unipotent matrix. [Recall that a $n\times n$ matrix $U$ is unipotent if $U-1$ is nilpotent, i.e., if $U$ has characteristic polynomial $(X-1)^n$.)

When the dimension $n$ is $3$, it is easy to check that for $A$ non-cyclic, $Y(A)$ consists of non-invertible matrices. (It is enough to do it for an algebraically closed field, and then take $A$ either diagonal with 2 eigenvalues, or nilpotent squaring to zero.) So one gets a positive answer for $p=3$, confirming your result without computation.

For $n=5$, I tried with the diagonal matrix $(0,1,2,3,0)$, so $Y(A)$ consists of those matrices for which the diagonal is zero as well as the two corner entries $u_{15},u_{51}$. Over $\mathbf{F}_5$ there are $5^{18}$ such matrices which is a bit large, but what's easy is to take random entries. There are only $5^4=625$ a priori possible characteristic polynomials (since the trace is zero), so with a small number ($<10000$) of random choices one expects to get the desired characteristic polynomial $(X-1)^5$. It worked (and actually all 625 characteristic polynomials are achieved).

One example is the unipotent matrix over $\mathbf{F}_5$
$$u=\begin{pmatrix}0&4&3&2&0\\1&0&0&1&2\\3&3&0&0&2\\2&3&1&0&3\\0&4&1&0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$
(In your notation, take $N=u-1$, which is nilpotent)

---

Edit: even with $A$ the diagonal matrix $(0,1,2,1,0)$ (which has larger commutator, hence smaller $Y()$), it works. Here being in $Y$ means that both the diagonal and antidiagonal are zero. Namely 
$$u'=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&4&1&0\\1&0&4&0&2\\0&3&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0&4\\0&0&3&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$ 
is unipotent (in characteristic $5$) and also all 625 characteristic polynomials with trace zero are achieved by elements of $Y(A)$.

Comment: well done Yves, thanks. I also did random tests for n=5; but I gave myself I+J, where J is the nilpotent Jordan block of dimension p and I looked for non-cyclic A. In short, I haven't found a counterexample. I may have programmed the PC incorrectly.
​